# Excel pivot on analysis server slow, same cross table in powerbi desktop is fast

Tags: excel, powerbi-desktop, azure-analysis-services

My customer wants to continue using Excel pivot.

We have a tabular model in azure analysis server.

When making a pivot on 2 columns (1 from the fact, 1 from the dimension table), it is very slow and a memory allocation error occurs.

Making the same selection in pbi desktop in a table, is no problem.

What is the difference? Both are live connections on tabular, no import.

The excel connections connects to a perspective of the model.
When applying a measure to the pivot it works, but the pivot (in straight table format) should also be possible to show without a measure.

Purpose is to quickly drag & drop all required attributes into the pivot, just like in PBI desktop.

Thanks,

Johan.